# Skip the true value of an if statement on the first occurence

Tags: excel

I have a list of unique numbers and duplicates as shown below

[image]

`=IF(AND(S1=S2,Y1=Y2),B1,B1+1)`

I am counting the Duplicates as shown below

[image: `]

`=IF(OR(Y2="txt",Y2="txt1"),1,COUNTIF(B:B,B2))`

And with this result i would like to add the value 55 to each duplicate that is >1 . BUT! i would like to skip the first row of each duplicate and only add to the second and so forth. In short for the first duplicate of each occurrence i would only like to do `AA2/AB2` the false bit of the if statement.
For example if i have 3 duplicates , i would like to only add 55 to the last 2 of them.

[image]

`=IF(AB2>1,(55+AA2)/AB2,AA2/AB2)`

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55429941/edit) to provide sample data and explain exactly what the expected outcome is, it would be helpful

Comment: Edited, hopefully it's more clear now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(OR(Y2="TXT1",Y2="TXT2"),1,IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,$B2)>1,COUNTIF(B:B,B2),1))`

Just in case anyone faces the same problem.
Managed to figure out the logic behind it.
This piece of code will count the duplicates while leaving the first occurrence as 1.